# Packaging imported javascript into svelte component using rollup

Tags: rollupjs, svelte, svelte-component

In my code, I want to import an external javascript file that is common across multiple components. When rollup builds the component, however, it has trouble resolving the imported dependency so it never gets included in the output package. Note, I'm trying to build a svelte component (as opposed to a svelte app) although I'm not sure that makes a difference. Here is my rollup.config.js:

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import pkg from './package.json';

const name = pkg.name
    .replace(/^(@\S+\/)?(svelte-)?(\S+)/, '$3')
    .replace(/^\w/, m => m.toUpperCase())
    .replace(/-\w/g, m => m[1].toUpperCase());

export default {
    input: 'src/Radar.html',
    output: [
        { sourcemap: true, file: pkg.module, 'format': 'es' },
        { sourcemap: true, file: pkg.main, 'format': 'umd', name }
    ],
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            cascade: false,
            store: true
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: What does the import declaration inside `src/Radar.html` look like? If it's importing from `node_modules` then you will need to use [rollup-plugin-node-resolve](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve) (and possibly [rollup-plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs))

Comment: It's not importing from node_modules but that's good info for the future. I've tried literally every form I can think of from 3 different forms of ES6 `import` and several forms of `require()`. I put them just inside the script tag.

Comment: can you post the whole thing as a gist?

Comment: @LarryMaccherone I think this question should be closed. It is more than 1 year old, is specific to your setup at the time, and it misses the relevant information to be solved by someone here (your actual code & error message). If your still interested in solving this, please add the missing info. If you have solved it yourself, maybe post the solution for others to see. If you're still interested in answers about packaging of Svelte libs in general, I think you should ask another question about that and not mention this project-specific problem that makes it unanswerable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve dependency there is a [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-node-resolve) for `Rollup`:

```js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import pkg from './package.json';

const name = pkg.name
    .replace(/^(@\S+\/)?(svelte-)?(\S+)/, '$3')
    .replace(/^\w/, m => m.toUpperCase())
    .replace(/-\w/g, m => m[1].toUpperCase());

export default {
    input: 'src/Radar.html',
    output: [
        { sourcemap: true, file: pkg.module, 'format': 'es' },
        { sourcemap: true, file: pkg.main, 'format': 'umd', name }
    ],
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            cascade: false,
            store: true
        }),
        resolve()
    ]
};
```

I assume that `Radar.html` is a Svelte module, i.e. you can rename it to `Radar.svelte`.